# How exactly am I supposed to test business expectations?

Tags: bdd

I have been looking at BDD but there is something that keeps confusing me. Consider this user story:

```
Given a user has placed their order
And the payment was accepted
Then a confirmation email should be sent.
```

Based on this, I see different things being done:

- Some sort of functional test to see whether an actual email was sent with a certain subject/content
- Something that is closer to a unit test by testing the domain object behaviour, ie. asserting the value of a property like `sendConfirmationEmail`.

I guess I am confused about what exactly one is supposed to test in BDD, because "business expectations" is a bit vague. In the above user story, which of the two mentioned approaches is the one that is "appropriate"?

Comment: I'd use Dependency Injection to pass in a fake EmailService and verify it is called correctly.

Comment: But if you believe the business will get more value by building out an integrated test that verifies an actual email was sent, then do so.  Both are appropriate in different situations.  It comes down to the cost to implement vs the value gained for your business.

Comment: @bitsoflogic Does that mean you would pass an EmailService to your domain object?

Comment: Yes. Either `new domainObj(EmailService)` or `domainObj.completeOrder(EmailService)`.

Comment: I was under the impression that domain objects shouldn't have service layer dependencies, but I'll do this now as suggested to keep things going.

Comment: @bitsoflogic So I did that and injected a fake Mailer class and checked that its methods were called as expected. My BDD tests passed, but no email got sent. I found out I had an error in my `LeadRepository`. I get the feeling that BDD without a **combination** of unit and integration tests to be kind of useless (as stated by Flater). I also don't understand how to use BDD to help find errors outside of the domain layer.

Comment: It's important to understand what the test is telling you. We are not creating complete proofs in the mathematical sense when we do testing. Each test verifies only the conditions of that test and no more. Testing *does not* ensure working software. It merely lets you know if the conditions you chose to test for are no longer true. This is great for finding regressions and helpful for guiding your own thinking towards more complete software. In your case, it told you that not sending an email wasn't a problem in the class with the fake Mailer, but was happening elsewhere.

Comment: @bitsoflogic `Testing does not ensure working software` The main reason I go through all this BDD complexity is to have more confidence in the code that I am deploying. I know this sounds ironic, because increased complexity leads to more errors. I believe BDD can help with that. But until it does, it's just another code base that I need to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Your two options actually test two different things:

> Some sort of functional test to see whether an actual email was sent with a certain subject/content

Is the application **able** to send an email? This is *either* an integration test *or* a unit test of the actual mail sender object (or both).

> Something that is closer to a unit test by testing the domain object behaviour, ie. asserting the value of a property like sendConfirmationEmail

Is the application **intending** to send an email? This is a unit test of your business logic object.

In the end, you're going to want to test both the first and the second, but your question (as asked) focuses on the second.

---

Bitsoflogic is correct on how to approach the BLL unit test:

> I'd use Dependency Injection to pass in a fake EmailService and verify it is called correctly.

Your suggestion of checking a boolean is not a good one, because the production code isn't going to be using this boolean. Your test can pass while your production code will fail (i.e. whatever your production code uses instead of the boolean contains a bug), which defeats the purpose of testing your application.

When you inject dependencies, you guarantee that the exact same code path that will be in production is going to be tested. The only thing different between the test and production runtime is the actual dependency you inject, but that doesn't matter as your unit test only focuses on testing the *current* class (not the dependency).

---

> I guess I am confused about what exactly one is supposed to test in BDD, because "business expectations" is a bit vague.

Simply put, you test your business logic, the "decision making" process. Does the business logic behave the way you intended it to behave?

Comment: The first test *also* tests whether the application is intending to send a mail.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: It shouldn't. It should be a direct test of `MailSender.SendMail()`, it should not test the _caller_ of the `SendMail()` method, because `SendMail()` may have many different callers. What you're suggesting amounts to scope creep of your tests. Whether someone decides to call this method or not, is not part of the test which focuses on making sure the method works (a mail gets sent) when the method is called. This test assumes that there is a (fixed) intent to send the email because it works under the premise that the `SendMail()` method is being called.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Very simply put, when you are testing if your doorbell works, then you are testing if it makes a sound when you press the button. You are not testing whether you should have pressed the button or not. That test ("do you know when you should or shouldn't be ringing my doorbell?") is a completely different test from "does my doorbell work?".

Comment: A test which places an order and then verifies that an e-mail was received does test both things. This isn't about individual methods or about something in the code, it's about testing the system as a whole. About the doorbell analogy: it's more like testing package delivery. If you order a package and then you hear the postman ringing your bell, then you have also tested that the doorbell works, as part of the order and delivery process. You can additionally test the doorbell itself, but that test may be of little value if the whole process already works fine.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: That is an integration test, which I already acknowledged in my answer, and more importantly, is not the focus of OP's question based on the provided use case. However, I vehemently disagree with the underlying suggestion in your comment that integration tests can be used in lieu of unit tests. While an integration test success would often implicitly also confirm an underlying unit test's success, that is not always true (e.g. two wrongs making a right). But more importantly, an integration test failure tells you nothing whether the underlying unit test itself would pass/fail.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: To extend your analogy: if the doorbell _doesn't_ ring; how are you able to know whether the doorbell is broken, or that the mailman never pressed the button? You seem to be focusing solely on the happy path, but are forgetting that when the test does fail, you have no idea of knowing which of the parts failed. That is a massive drawback that effectively negates a big and important benefit of having unit tests.

Comment: `In the end, you're going to want to test both the first and the second`. Does this mean my scenario would have to run both unit and integration tests at the same time?

Comment: @Michael: Ideally yes. There are reasons to run them at separate times (e.g. if a developer can quickly confirm unit tests locally but not integration tests), but you should only consider the full (unit+integration) test result as a meaningful outcome. Half of a testing result does not conclusively answer if the codebase works as intended. The only reason you'd half-test is to do an optional pre-check so you e.g. don't have to start the big/slow/cumbersome deep testing when the fast/light/easy pre-test already fails. That's a practical argument, not a technical one.

Comment: You are exaggerating the "you have no idea what's wrong" part. A failing integration test is always followed up by an in-depth analysis of the error. Unit tests can be considered *one* way of performing such an analysis, but they are far from being the only way to find bugs and problems in your components. Consider log analysis, debugging and code reviews. In fact, there are integration test failures where an error message itself may state the obvious reason for the failure. You argue as if we were completely helpless to find the causes of errors without unit tests.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Unit tests preclude the need for an in-depth analysis. At least, they provide you with an accurate response of _which_ part actually failed. `Consider log analysis, debugging and code reviews` all of which are considerably more cumbersome than running unit tests. They do help in figuring what went wrong in the part that failed its unit test, but it's an inferior approach if you rely on this to tell you _which_ part failed the test. Your anti-unit-test argument may apply to some people in some cases but it is wholly out of scope of the question and my answer.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: You're arguing just to argue (1) Obviously, the cumbersome test argument only applies in cases where cumbersome tests exist. (2) At no point did I argue that integration tests have no value when all unit tests pass. I stated quite the opposite. (3) Advocating the skipping of unit tests in favor of integration tests is decidedly not (nor does it counter) the topic of the answer I provided here,

Comment: @Flater I finished my tests and their implementation and they all pass, but I have very little confidence that my app "works", because the state of the live app is usually much more complex than the one I create for the tests. Even if I have unit + integration tests in place, I am only ever going to test whether the business logic part of the application works under the conditions that I create for the test, or am I mistaken?